Claimed proofs of graph labelling conjectures
The following recent series of arXiv papers claims to prove several of the most famous graph labelling conjectures. Edinah Gnang is the common author, none of the papers seem to be published further, and all are based on variants of Gnang's so-called composition lemma. Has anyone verified the correctness of these results, or found an error?
A Proof of the Tree Packing Conjecture, https://arxiv.org/abs/2410.13840
All trees on $n$ edges decompose $K_{n,n}$,
https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.01981
A proof of the Kotzig-Ringel-Rosa Conjecture, https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.03178
A proof of the Graham Sloane conjecture, https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.02240
On graceful labelings of trees, https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07614
On The Composition Lemma, https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12812

I've voted to close, and I chose from the list of reasons that this is a request to check the correctness of a preprint.  Since the common author of these papers is (I think!) an untenured assistant professor, I believe it is particularly important to not have a critical discussion in a forum like this.

(by "forum like this", I mean one that allows anyone to contribute including anonymous people)

Fair enough. I welcome non-anonymous answers to my question by email.

cstheory.stackexchange has a related question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54427/is-gnangs-proof-of-graceful-tree-conjecture-correct
